# C shared global variables reset in JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, global-variables, shared-libraries

Currently at work I am having trouble with global variables in C shared library under JNI. The objective is to compile a database source code into a shared library to use it natively in a Java application.

Before compiling the shared library, I compile the source code using its regular Makefile (the process is too verbose to show here). Then I compile the shared library as follows:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -DPIC -g -o ../java-lite/src/main/resources/libmonetdb5.so `find common gdk mal/mal mal/modules mal/optimizer sql embedded -name "*.o" | tr "\n" " "` -lpthread -lpcre -lz -lm -ldl
```

Then I do the Maven compilation:

```
mvn clean install
```

On the Java side I just load the shared library at the application's bootstrap.

```
static {
    try {
        // Try load the library from java.library.path (it's working)
        System.loadLibrary("monetdb5");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
         //Load the library from the jar otherwise
        loadLibFromJar("monetdb5");
    }
}
```

The problem is occurring right on the database loading. Here it is the JNI call:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_nl_cwi_monetdb_embedded_MonetDBEmbeddedInstance_StartDatabase(JNIEnv *env, jclass class, jstring dbDirectory, jboolean silentFlag, jboolean sequentialFlag) {
    const char *dbdir_string_tmp = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, dbDirectory, 0);
    char silent_char = 0, sequential_char = 0, *err = NULL, *databaseDirectory = strdup(dbdir_string_tmp);
    jclass resultClass;
    jmethodID resultConstructor;

    (void)class;
    if (silentFlag) {
        silent_char = 1;
    }
    if (sequentialFlag) {
        sequential_char = 1;
    }
    err = monetdb_startup(databaseDirectory, 1, 0);
    if (err != NULL) {
        (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, dbDirectory, dbdir_string_tmp);
        resultClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/io/IOException");
        (*env)->ThrowNew(env, resultClass, err);
        return NULL;
    }
    resultClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "nl/cwi/monetdb/embedded/MonetDBEmbeddedInstance");
    resultConstructor = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, resultClass, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;ZZZ)V");
    return (*env)->NewObject(env, resultClass, resultConstructor, dbDirectory, silentFlag, sequentialFlag, 1);
}
```

Then the monetdb_startup function from the database source code:

```
static int monetdb_embedded_initialized = 0;

void* monetdb_connect(void) {
    Client conn = NULL;
    if (!monetdb_embedded_initialized) {
        return NULL;
    }
    conn = MCforkClient(&mal_clients[0]);
    if (!MCvalid((Client) conn)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (SQLinitClient(conn) != MAL_SUCCEED) {
        return NULL;
    }
    ((backend *) conn->sqlcontext)->mvc->session->auto_commit = 1;
    return conn;
}

char* monetdb_startup(char* dbdir, char silent, char sequential) {
    opt *set = NULL;
    volatile int setlen = 0;
    str retval = MAL_SUCCEED;
    char* sqres = NULL;
    void* res = NULL;
    void* c;

    if (setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "") == NULL) {
        retval = GDKstrdup("setlocale() failed");
        goto cleanup;
    }
    GDKfataljumpenable = 1;
    if(setjmp(GDKfataljump) != 0) {
        retval = GDKfatalmsg;
        // we will get here if GDKfatal was called.
        if (retval == NULL) {
            retval = GDKstrdup("GDKfatal() with unspecified error?");
        }
        goto cleanup;
    }

    if (monetdb_embedded_initialized) goto cleanup;

    if (!mal_init_inline) {
        mz_ulong decompress_len_mal = EMBEDDED_SCRIPT_SIZE_MAX;
        mz_ulong decompress_len_sql = EMBEDDED_SCRIPT_SIZE_MAX;
        mal_init_inline = GDKzalloc(decompress_len_mal);
        createdb_inline = GDKzalloc(decompress_len_sql);
        if (!mal_init_inline || !createdb_inline) {
            retval = GDKstrdup("Memory allocation failed");
            goto cleanup;
        }
        if (mz_uncompress(mal_init_inline, &decompress_len_mal, mal_init_inline_arr, sizeof(mal_init_inline_arr)) != 0 ||
            mz_uncompress(createdb_inline, &decompress_len_sql, createdb_inline_arr, sizeof(createdb_inline_arr)) != 0) {
            retval = GDKstrdup("Script decompression failed");
            goto cleanup;
        }
    }

    setlen = mo_builtin_settings(&set);
    setlen = mo_add_option(&set, setlen, opt_cmdline, "gdk_dbpath", dbdir);

    BBPaddfarm(dbdir, (1 << PERSISTENT) | (1 << TRANSIENT));
    if (GDKinit(set, setlen) == 0) {
        retval = GDKstrdup("GDKinit() failed");
        goto cleanup;
    }
    GDKsetenv("monet_mod_path", "");
    GDKsetenv("mapi_disable", "true");
    if (sequential) {
        GDKsetenv("sql_optimizer", "sequential_pipe");
    }

    if (silent) THRdata[0] = stream_blackhole_create();

    if (mal_init() != 0) { // mal_init() does not return meaningful codes on failure
        retval = GDKstrdup("mal_init() failed");
        goto cleanup;
    }

    if (silent) mal_clients[0].fdout = THRdata[0];

    monetdb_embedded_initialized = 1;
    c = monetdb_connect();
    if (c == NULL) {
        monetdb_embedded_initialized = 0;
        retval = GDKstrdup("Failed to initialize client");
        goto cleanup;
    }
    GDKfataljumpenable = 0;

    // we do not want to jump after this point, since we cannot do so between threads
    // sanity check, run a SQL query
    sqres = monetdb_query(c, "SELECT * FROM tables;", 1, &res);
    if (sqres != NULL) {
        monetdb_embedded_initialized = 0;
        retval = sqres;
        goto cleanup;
    }
    monetdb_cleanup_result(c, res);
    monetdb_disconnect(c);
cleanup:
    mo_free_options(set, setlen);
    return retval;
```

}

We have a global variable "monetdb_embedded_initialized" which indicates if the database has been initialized yet or not. On the "monetdb_startup" function, we set the variable to 1 and then we create a brief connection on "monetdb_connect" function to make a small functional test with a basic SQL query. There we have to check if "monetdb_embedded_initialized" is set to 1 or not (for posterior connections as well).

The problem is that after setting monetdb_embedded_initialized to 1 on "monetdb_startup", on "monetdb_connect" the variable is read as 0, like it never changed. I tested with other global variables, and in fact this behavior also happens.

I checked on GDB that there is only one thread calling these functions, also this variable is only used on these functions. Strangely on GDB using

```
p monetdb_embedded_initialized
```

before each read is showing the correct values. I also checked the symbols with "nm libmonetdb5.so", and all of them are there.

I know that global variables are very problematic in general, but I would prefer to keep them, because the database source code has lots of them, and removing them would take us too long time.

Thanks for your attention

Comment: You mean, `monetdb_query(c, "SELECT * FROM tables;", 1, &res)` always returns NULL?

Comment: @AlexCohn Hello! No, the problem is inside after updating "monetdb_embedded_initialized" to 1 in the beginning of monetdb_startup,  in the "monetdb_connect" call, this variable is read as 0 instead of 1, like it never changed before, but that's not true.

Comment: If I read your code correctly, **monetdb_startup()** will reset `monetdb_embedded_initialized` to **0** if `monetdb_query(c, "SELECT * FROM tables;", 1, &res)` returns **NULL**.

Comment: Yes! However the problem is in this check `if (!monetdb_embedded_initialized) {
        return NULL;
    }` in **monetdb_connect**

Comment: or if first **monetdb_connect()** returns NULL. Add print log there to be sure

Comment: **monetdb_startup** is always called first. Then **monetdb_connect** can be called upon for new connections. I placed breakpoints at both functions on GDB and it's working as expected.

Comment: But you said that with GDB you get the expected value, don't you?

Comment: Yes, on GDB the "monetdb_embedded_initialized" variable always shows the correct values.

Comment: That's why it's worth adding some print to log statements, and try to figure out what goes wrong when you run w/o a debugger attached

Comment: Hello, i know it's old but i'm experiencing the same kind of issue. Did you solve this issue ? Do you remember how ?